# How it the level of detail texture loading called

Tags: terminology

Borderlands 2 uses this technique:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDKOndosFAg

Some games use techniques to load textures progressively in some level of detail way.
I can not find any material on this topic or any terms.
How is it called and how is it done?

Comment: It looks like they're loading the smallest mip levels of each texture first, then introducing more detail as it streams from storage. Are you familiar with [mipmapping](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap)?

Comment: @Benedikt S. Vogler curious to know the link which you shown how you come to conclusion of progressively texture loading. The difference loading 0:18 sec was one which is visible btwn the comparison.
Ys mipmapping concept I used it unity provide this with http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/237793/how-do-you-use-mipmaps.html
Plus worth checking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148795/android-opengl-texture-compression texture compression I used DDS in my game and better performance then png Hope this help sorry if you already know this Happy coding